# Update and convert value of a column at the same time without using code server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with following columns:

```
id   |   title  |   date
1    | Title A  | 15-06-2013
2    | Title B  | 25-06-2013
3    | Title C  | 05-07-2013
4    | Title D  | 19-09-2013
```

Now I need to change `date` column to Unix `timestamp` so it can be something like this:

```
id   |   title  |   date
1    | Title A  | 1756346212
2    | Title B  | 1883216212
3    | Title C  | 1227346212
4    | Title D  | 1956436212
```

Can I use a SQL statement to process the `update` and convert at the same time without using code server? As code server i just need to do this:

```
select each row => covert `date` to unix time stamp => update
```

will be something like that with a SQL statement?

Comment: What is a "code server"? Also, what format are you storing the date in? You should nearly always use date formats for dates, not an integer timestamp. You can convert from date to timestamp quite easily, either in MySQL or in the program that connects to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If date is a varchar column, and you want to convert it to unix timestamp, I would do it this way:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD COLUMN unixdate int;

UPDATE yourtable
SET unixdate = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d-%m-%Y'));

ALTER TABLE yourtable DROP COLUMN date;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3680/1). Or if you just need a SELECT, you could use this:

```
SELECT id, title, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y')) `date`
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: Solved my problem, you save me much time. Thanks